# What is the whole process for sending Intent in Android framework?

Tags: android, android-intent

As much as I understand, when a component broadcasts `Intent`, it triggers `ActivityManager` and `PackageManager` to match appropriate components to receive the `Intent`. In this process, what is the role of `ReferenceMonitor`? What is the entire process of sending `Intent` in the middleware level?

Comment: This question is far too vague. If you want to know exactly how it works, read the source code. If you have a specific problem, please refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the white paper [Deep Dive into Android IPC/Binder Framework](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1340/Deep_Dive_Into_Binder_Presentation.htm) by Aleksandar (Saša) Gargenta very insightful.